# Display Parent / child list in one Grails view

Tags: grails

I am attempting to display a 1 to many relationship on one view using grails 2.2.1.

Essentially, I want to use one view to display two lists (one parent list, one child list). Further, I want to create a call to the controller to display the proper child records in the child list based upon which record is selected in the parent list. The domains would look like this...

```
class Parent{
    string name
    string attribute

    static hasMany = [children : Child]

}


class Child{
    string name
    string childattribute

    static belongsTo = [parent: Parent]

}
```

The Parent controller would be ...

```
class AppstackController {

static scaffold = Appstack

def index ={
   def parent = Parent.list()
   def childList= parent?.child
   render(view: "list", model:[parentlist: Parent.list(), childList: childList])
}

def getChildren = {
    def parent= Appstack.get(params.id)
    def childList= parent?.child
    render (view: "list", model:[childList: childList])
}


}
```

I want to be able to call the getChildren action and update the child list on the view by clicking on the row in the parent list. I assume that this could be accomplished withe remoteLink or remoteFunction .

What should the controller and view code look like to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

gsp:
You need to include jquery

```
      <g:each in="${ parentlist}" var="FoundParent">

                <button id=whatever 
onclick="<g:remoteFunction controller="AppstackController"  
        action="getChildren" update="myBOX"  
        id="${FoundParent.id}"  params="${[name:FoundParent.name,param2:'something']}"/>">
        FoundParent.name</button>
     </g:each>
                 <div id=myBox>
                   <g:each in="${childList}" var="FoundChild">
                            ${FoundChild.name}
               </g:each>
                 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use GET http request. Anyway you can add AJAX request after. How to use AJAX see Grails docs.

```
class ParentController {

    def index(){ redirect action: 'list' }

    def list(){
        [parents: Parent.list()]
    }

    def show(long id){
       def parent = Parent.get(id)
       if (!parent) { redirect: action:'list'; return }

       //prepare model
       model=[:]
       model.parents = Parent.list()
       model.parent = parent
       render view:'list', model:model
    }

}
```

${parent?.children} in GSP give you Set of child. You can use "g:each" Tag.

**GSP**

```
<ul>
   <g:each in="${parents}" var="p">
   <li class="selectable ${ p==parent?'selected': ''}">
      <g:link action="show" id="${p.id}">
          ${p.name}
      </g:link>
   </li>
   </g:each>
</ul>

<ul>
   <g:each in="${parent?.children}" var="child">
   <li>
      ${child.name}
   </li>
   </g:each>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li.selectable{}
li.selectable:HOVER{ border: 1px solid gray;}
li.selected{ border: 1px solid gray; background-color: silver;}
```